# How do I read a Linux environment variable into install4j

Tags: install4j

My application sets CLASSPATH in a shell script named shrc that sets up the environment to run java commands.  Is there an easy way to pass the CLASSPATH used in an installed application to install4j so I can use it in an action? The working solution I have uses "Run executable or batch file" to run a script that does this:

```
  . ./shrc
  ${APPHOME}/jre/bin/java -cp ${CLASSPATH} ...etc...
```

I do this within an add-on installer, so the shrc already exists, but I need to run some of the existing java code to configure the patches.

It seems to me there must be a better way to do this that would work on Windows also.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a way to run ./shrc and capture the value for CLASSPATH set by shrc to set an install4j variable?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read environment variables, use

```
System.getenv("CLASSPATH")
```

If you would like to use it as an install4j installer variable, add a "Set a variable" action with the above line as the script.